# How can I make Intellisense reference a JS file in another folder?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

(Edit: Updated with more information of things I've tried and problems I've encountered.)

I'm trying to make Intellisense recognize and utilize a JS file in a common folder in my project. My current structure looks like this:

- `.vscode`

  - `launch.json`
- `common`

  - `jsconfig.json`
  - `MyLib.js`
- `tests`

  - `jsconfig.json`
  - `index.html`
  - `runtests.js`
- `demo`

  - `jsconfig.json`
  - `index.html`
  - `demo.js`

`MyLib.js` is simply:

```
function MyLib(){}
MyLib.prototype = { constructor: MyLib };
```

My `demo/jsconfig.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5"
    },
    "include": [
        "../common/MyLib.js"
    ]
}
```

Now, when I'm editing `demo.js`, I start to type: `var x = new MyL`... And nothing happens.

Am I missing something in my configuration? Does it require documentation of some kind?

**Update:**

I updated my `demo/jsconfig.json` to look like this (adding `files` like Matt Bierner suggested):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5"
  },
  "files": [
    "demo.js",
  ],
  "include": [
    "../common/MyLib.js"
  ]
}
```

...and I was able to see `MyLib` in the suggestions, but an object I created in `demo.js`...

```
var x = new MyLib();
```

...`x` wasn't able to see any of the properties of `MyLib`, which is (IMO) the point of Intellisense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try configuring the project so that it includes both files, either using the `files` option to explicitly list all the files in your project:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5"
  },
  "files": [
    "demo.js",
    "../common/MyLib.js"
  ]
}
```

or using an `include` option:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5"
  },
  "files": [
    "demo.js",
  },
  "include": {
    "./**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

Using this config, I see the suggestions in `demo.js` for `MyLib`. [Here's more information about the jsconfig options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Comment: I tried it both ways, and both allow me to see `MyLib` in `demo.js`, but that's where Intellisense seems to end. If I have `var x = new MyLib();`, entering `x.` on the next line only gives in-file suggestions ("MyLib" and "x"). I don't see `MyLib`'s prototype nor its constructor in the suggestions. (P.S. Your link went to the docs for `tsconfig.json`, but I'm not using TypeScript at all. Does that matter?)

Comment: This seems like a bug with TypeScript (which powers the VSCode JS language features). I've opened two bugs to track this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15162 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15163 . Also, a `jsconfig` is pretty much a `tsconfig`  with any TypeScript specific config options removed. The documentation should apply to both

Comment: Thanks for filing the bugs. I'm re-reading the documentation on JavaScript in VSCode as well. If I come up with anything, I'll update my post.

Comment: I see the bug for this just got fixed/closed. Will this be in the next Insiders build? If so, I'll grab a copy and test it, so I can finally accept this answer. :)

Comment: Should already be in VS Code 1.19 with TS 2.6 I believe. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15163 still needs to be fixed

Comment: I'm still seeing `x` resolve as an `any` in 1.19.2. Should I comment on the bug in github?

Comment: Yes, please open a new issue against typescript with a complete, self-contained code example, and reference the closed bug

Comment: Just noticed the bug marked the changes as part of the TS 2.7 milestone. The current release is 2.6.2, so I'll hold off until I can verify in 2.7. Maybe the other will be resolved by then, too. :)